# Can we increase the size of the Alertbox using NSAlert in objective-c coding

Tags: objective-c, macos, alert

I want to show pop-up message in my project developed in Xcode (Objective-C). I am using `NSAlert` for popup design. As the text I want to display is more, I want customize my pop-up box size. Is there any way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change your *NSAlert* size using something like this:

```
NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
NSRect frame = alert.window.frame;
frame.size.height = 110;
frame.size.width = 210;
[alert.window setFrame:frame display:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an accessory view to enlarge your NSAlert:

```
NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
alert.accessoryView = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 500, 0)];
```

Credit: [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26502127/6059640)

Answer (score 1):

NSAlert does not allow you to change its window. So you will need to write your own window controller subclass like NSAlert which is a subclass of NSObject. Pl. refer the below link, 
  1. [NSAlert resize window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820335/nsalert-resize-window)
  2. [Creating a fully customized NSAlert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277295/creating-a-fully-customized-nsalert?rq=1)
where the options are provided to customize the alert view.

Also you can take a look of the iOS custom alertview form the below github link
https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview