# Set width of NSAlert Window

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsalert

i use this code for show a nsalert message:

```
let alert = NSAlert()
alert.informativeText = "My Text"
alert.addButton(withTitle: "Button 1")
alert.addButton(withTitle: "Button 2")
alert.runModal()
```

is there a way to set the width value of the alert window?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820335/nsalert-resize-window?rq=1

Comment: thank you for this information. i tried this: `alert.accessoryView = NSView(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 500.0, 0))` and I can see, that this change the width to 500.0. but i need a smaller size. is it possible, that the alert has a minimum width? it does not make any difference if i set 100.0 or 150.0. i can't set it smaller.

Comment: Don't use `NSAlert`, create your own dialog.

Comment: how can i do this? is there an documentation for this?

Comment: Use `presentViewControllerAsModalWindow(_:)` or create a window and use `runModal(for:)`.

Comment: ahh okay, like this way. thank you very much :)